# How can we find texture patterns in images in java?

Tags: android-image

I am working in app which uses machine vision. The app identifies whether the image contains a apple or an orange . I need a way to check the texture in the image. The image is in form of byte[]. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not clear what are you asking...  If your question is how to check if image contains apple or orange, you should ask it rather on machine-learning community than on stackoverflow

Comment: I just want to a simple code snippet to detect color or texture in an image (byte[])

Comment: So you want to make recognition just by color? Is it red(green?) or orange?

Comment: Yes , it should only detect colors red and orange

Comment: Can you please post code that you use to read the image?

Comment: I am reading the image pixel by pixel in byte[] . That is by row and column.

Comment: so it's RGBRGBRGB... ?

Comment: Yes exactly, you are right.

Comment: What about background? Background also have color. It could be red or orange.

Comment: The background could be any dark color which shows contrast between the object and the background.

Comment: ok, so just count are there more orange or red pixels(excluding black ones)?